# krigeST error with STIDF and STFDF object

Tags: r, spatial, kriging, gstat, covariogram

I want to produce daily, weekly and monthly kriged maps[var1.pred is the output I am looking for](https://github.com/r-spatial/gstat/pull/108).I created STIDF object with temporal Units in the variogram model following [link for temporal Units](https://github.com/r-spatial/gstat/pull/108). I get an error when running krigeST.
Error is: Error in chol.default(A) : the leading minor of order 3 is not positive
I know this error is because of duplicates as per [issues associated to error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25063157/r-error-in-chol-defaulta-krigest-from-gstat-package). But I need duplicates because one of the parameter varies which is shown with light condition.

For weekly and monthly averages I created STFDF object which has no duplicates but shows another error.
Error is:Error in na.fail.default(list(value = c(8.1925753837777, 22.0429913536433,  : missing values in object
which is because of NA values, but omitting NA values removes all the values from STFDF object.

timelag for STIDF object with empirical variogram shows values such as 15,45 [empirical variogram output of STIDF object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTF0D.png)whereas for STFDF object it shows days [empirical variogram output of STIDF aggregated to weeks an STFDF object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNSRM.png).Why does it mean?

Data Structure

```
dput(head(time,50))
structure(list(ID = c(783, 784, 845, 846, 907, 908, 966, 1024, 
1081, 1, 2, 3, 61, 62, 63, 121, 122, 123, 181, 182, 183, 237, 
238, 239, 293, 294, 295, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 426, 427, 428, 
429, 430, 495, 496, 497, 498, 499, 571, 572, 573, 574, 575, 645, 
646, 647), time = c("11:00:00", "15:00:00", "11:00:00", "15:00:00", 
"11:00:00", "15:00:00", "11:00:00", "11:00:00", "11:00:00", "11:00:00", 
"15:00:00", "19:00:00", "11:00:00", "15:00:00", "19:00:00", "11:00:00", 
"15:00:00", "19:00:00", "11:00:00", "15:00:00", "19:00:00", "11:00:00", 
"15:00:00", "19:00:00", "11:00:00", "15:00:00", "19:00:00", "07:00:00", 
"11:00:00", "15:00:00", "19:00:00", "24:00:00", "07:00:00", "11:00:00", 
"15:00:00", "19:00:00", "24:00:00", "07:00:00", "11:00:00", "15:00:00", 
"19:00:00", "24:00:00", "07:00:00", "11:00:00", "15:00:00", "19:00:00", 
"24:00:00", "07:00:00", "11:00:00", "15:00:00"), date. = structure(c(19544, 
19544, 19544, 19544, 19544, 19544, 19544, 19544, 19544, 19545, 
19545, 19545, 19545, 19545, 19545, 19545, 19545, 19545, 19545, 
19545, 19545, 19545, 19545, 19545, 19545, 19545, 19545, 19547, 
19547, 19547, 19547, 19547, 19547, 19547, 19547, 19547, 19547, 
19547, 19547, 19547, 19547, 19547, 19547, 19547, 19547, 19547, 
19547, 19547, 19547, 19547), class = "Date"), light.condition = c("light", 
"light", "light", "light", "light", "light", "dark", "dark", 
"dark", "light", "light", "light", "light", "light", "light", 
"light", "light", "light", "dark", "dark", "dark", "dark", "dark", 
"dark", "dark", "dark", "dark", "light", "light", "light", "light", 
"light", "light", "light", "light", "light", "light", "light", 
"light", "light", "light", "light", "dark", "dark", "dark", "dark", 
"dark", "dark", "dark", "dark"), value = c(9.71401740645347, 
6.67113336110194, 22.2683202886655, 21.8176624186212, 1.10941911224629, 
1.06500494060907, 8.14032847129926, 21.4166772666492, 1.18754247027769, 
0.0550587583781332, 0.0908023190127035, -0.0287235863761574, 
-0.669267461955569, -0.0999384615406973, -0.467014583537735, 
-0.753432013505277, -0.0399606378578826, -0.365409650446191, 
-0.279498941786479, -0.0769385885223229, -0.252105706894821, 
-0.650782191920685, -0.906986174981546, -1.05863160747964, -0.485452126906809, 
-0.925896081018024, -1.04278402652926, 0.415677741263201, 0.277695366178094, 
0.266598920484192, 0.296489601928946, 0.450302004553194, 0.18961979977428, 
0.186103097004661, 0.181460098328402, 0.219629416931167, 0.201007497364092, 
0.188124540529136, 0.14345259055834, 0.153335645962729, 0.134674763692412, 
0.167406242060629, 0.275140881978198, 0.319478289598817, 0.288869076687038, 
0.342902199465362, 0.347413584337766, 0.158633196058699, 0.181909102924666, 
0.20224766775325), lat = c(68.623823, 68.623823, 68.623877, 68.623877, 
68.623781, 68.623781, 68.623823, 68.623877, 68.623781, 68.623899, 
68.623899, 68.623899, 68.623843, 68.623843, 68.623843, 68.623944, 
68.623944, 68.623944, 68.623899, 68.623899, 68.623899, 68.623843, 
68.623843, 68.623843, 68.623944, 68.623944, 68.623944, 68.624034, 
68.624034, 68.624034, 68.624034, 68.624034, 68.624093, 68.624093, 
68.624093, 68.624093, 68.624093, 68.62398, 68.62398, 68.62398, 
68.62398, 68.62398, 68.624034, 68.624034, 68.624034, 68.624034, 
68.624034, 68.624093, 68.624093, 68.624093), long = c(-149.584395, 
-149.584395, -149.584574, -149.584574, -149.584725, -149.584725, 
-149.584395, -149.584574, -149.584725, -149.583522, -149.583522, 
-149.583522, -149.583303, -149.583303, -149.583303, -149.583483, 
-149.583483, -149.583483, -149.583522, -149.583522, -149.583522, 
-149.583303, -149.583303, -149.583303, -149.583483, -149.583483, 
-149.583483, -149.58195, -149.58195, -149.58195, -149.58195, 
-149.58195, -149.581698, -149.581698, -149.581698, -149.581698, 
-149.581698, -149.581512, -149.581512, -149.581512, -149.581512, 
-149.581512, -149.58195, -149.58195, -149.58195, -149.58195, 
-149.58195, -149.581698, -149.581698, -149.581698), class = "data.frame")
```

Time object

```
datetime_str <- paste(time$date., time$time)
starttime <- as.POSIXct(datetime_str, tz = '', tryFormats = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
time$startime = starttime
```

STIDF object

```
grd = data.frame(time)
coordinates(grd) = ~long + lat
proj4string(grd) <- CRS("+init=EPSG:6335")
valueSP = SpatialPoints(grd@coords,CRS("+init=epsg:6335"))
valueDF = data.frame(value=grd$value)
valueTM = grd$startime
stidf = STIDF(valueSP,valueTM,valueDF)
stplot(stidf,number=5,main="random days spatio-temporal values",as.table=T,colorkey=T )
```

Duplicates
`zerodist(stidf@sp)`
[duplicates in STIDF object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxc3C.png)

Variogram Model

```
metric <- vgmST("metric", joint = vgm(psill=182,model="Per",nugget=30,range=1), stAni=3)
attr(metric, "temporal unit")="days"
```

Kriging

```
pred.grd = SpatialPixels(SpatialPoints(makegrid(valueSP,n=69105)),proj4string = proj4string(valueSP))
n=10
tm.grd=xts(1:n,seq(min(index(stidf)),max(index(stidf)),length=n))
prediction.grd = STF(pred.grd,tm.grd)
pred <- krigeST(value~1, data=stidf, newdata=prediction.grd,metric,nmax=20,computeVar=TRUE)
```

Aggregate data to weeks/months
STFDF object
`x=aggregate(stidf,"weeks",mean,na.rm=TRUE)`

Duplicates for STFDF object
`zerodist(x@sp)`
[no duplicates for STFDF object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kY43A.png)

Empirical variogram STFDF object

```
var_stidf_weeks= variogramST(value ~ 1,data=x,tunit="weeks",tlags=0:5,assumeRegular=F)
sum(is.na(var_stidf_weeks))
var_stidf_weeks1=na.omit(var_stidf_weeks)
var_stidf_weeks1$dist=var_stidf_weeks1$dist*20
var_stidf_weeks1$gamma=var_stidf_weeks1$gamma/3
var_stidf_weeks1$timelag=var_stidf_weeks1$timelag*4
var_stidf_weeks1$avgDist=var_stidf_weeks1$avgDist*20
```

Fitting variogram

```
sumMetric <- vgmST("sumMetric", space = vgm(psill=46,model="Per",nugget=1,range=4),
                   time = vgm(psill=0.09,model="Exc",nugget=0.01,range=2),
                   joint = vgm(psill=1,model="Per",nugget=1,range=1), stAni=15)
sumMetric_Vgm <- fit.StVariogram(var_stidf_weeks1,sumMetric,stAni=3)
attr(sumMetric_Vgm, "temporal unit")="weeks"
```

Kriging prediction

```
tm.grd=xts(1:n,seq(min(index(x)),max(index(x)),length=n))
pred <- krigeST(value~1, data=x, STF(pred.grd,tm.grd),sumMetric_Vgm)
```

Just for comparison empirical variogram of STIDF

```
var_stidf_daily = variogramST(value~1,data=stidf,tunit="days",tlags=0:5,assumeRegular=F,na.omit=T, cores=4)
var_stidf_daily
sum(is.na(var_stidf_daily))
```